# Using Mamp, where do I go to set custom php values like memory limit?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, mamp

I am using Mamp for OSX.  Mamp Pro has handy File Menu options to access the php.ini and MySQL my.cnf files.  Just wondering where they are located for non-pro users.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I was blind, sorry, they are in

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php/conf/php.ini

you can find this by looking at php-info.

At least with Mamp version 3.0.2, you can easily access php-info from the Mamp start page.